# Javascript boostrap, The whole page appears duplicated in the modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

[My problem on screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZGDz.png)

I have a problem when the modal is triggered. The page is duplicate into the modal. The problem begin when i clicked the button with code:

```
<a href=<?php echo $route_destroy;?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Desactivar </a>
```

My html modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Confirm Submit
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to submit the following details?
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <td id="lname"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <td id="fname"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a href="#" id="submit" class="btn btn-success success">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
         /* when the submit button in the modal is clicked, submit the form */
        alert('submitting');
        $('#formfield').submit();
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell for sure without seeing your form and any JavaScript for it.

I think it may be because you are submitting the form without preventing the default action. Not doing so could cause the form to redirect to a page upon submission.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        alert('submitting');
        $('#formfield').submit(function(event) {
           // Add some JavaScript to change your modal here
           event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```